# System.ArgumentException when trying to find a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm making an "Online ATM" for an assignment using MVC.Net Framework, and Entity Framework. The problem I am having is as follows: One of the functions of my system is to allow users to make a transfer from one account to another. Below is the Post method for this action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Transfer(decimal TransferAmount, string AccTransfer, string accId, int id)
    {

        using (var ctx = new BankDBEntities())
        {


            AtmAccount acc = ctx.AtmAccounts.Find(id);

            if (ctx.AtmAccounts.Any(o => o.AccountNumber.Equals(AccTransfer)))
            {

                AtmAccount trans = ctx.AtmAccounts.Find(AccTransfer);

                if (acc.AccountBalance >= TransferAmount)
                {

                    acc.AccountBalance = acc.AccountBalance - TransferAmount;
                    trans.AccountBalance = trans.AccountBalance - TransferAmount;
                    ctx.Entry(acc).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    ctx.Entry(trans).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Transfer");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Transfer");
            }

        }
```

This method takes the TransferAmount and AccTransfer (the account to transfer to), as well as the account ID and user ID of the user making the transfer from, which are passed by the associated View Model. The problem appears to be in this line of code:

```
AtmAccount trans = ctx.AtmAccounts.Find(AccTransfer);
```

At this point, I get a System.ArgumentException reading "The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details." I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to get around this problem.

UPDATE TO THE PROBLEM:

After solving the issue above, I am now having an issue where the trans entity, for some reason, is null after trying to find AccTransfer in the table, which definitely exists.

Comment: AccTransfer is a string. It needs to be an int like your previous call. Try AtmAccount trans = ctx.AtmAccounts.Find(Int32.Parse(AccTransfer));

Comment: Okay great, that solved that problem. Now, for whatever reason, my "trans" entity seems to be null, even though AccTransfer is definitely present in AtmAccounts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it is the issue of type mismatch. It might be because the data type of the primary key property of this class- AccTransfer is not matching or different from the data type of the primary key of the actual entity object.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. However, AccTransfer is looking for the Account Number field, rather than the Id field of the table. The problem I have now, after changing AccTransfer to an int rather than a string, is that trans seems to come back as null. Changing Account Number in the AtmAccounts table to an int unfortunately causes other problems in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of a variable in .net and that of the corresponding column in the database should match.

In your case -

```
AccTransfer is string
```

But since it is an account number, I think in the database you must have mentioned it as an integer as the previous statement -

```
AtmAccount acc = ctx.AtmAccounts.Find(id);
```

works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reason might be that AccTransfer is not primary or AccTransfer is null or it cant find a record corresponding to AccTransfer, or you can use ctx.AtmAccounts.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.TransferAccount== AccTransfer)

Comment: I've checked this, AccTransfer is 125468 in my testing, which is the Account Number of a record in the AtmAccounts table. AccTransfer is never null, but for some reason trans cannot find AccTransfer in the table. Does Account Number need to be the primary key for me to be able to do this?

Comment: Yes Find() needs a primary key , or you can use  ctx.AtmAccounts.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.TransferAccount== AccTransfer)

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed, thank you so much!